# Can I hire someone to haul my waste monthly?

Tags: contract-law, civil-law

Can I hire an independent contractor to haul my waste in my city of Colusa, California. Someone said there is an exclusive contract that prevents the hauling of ones own waste to a landfill.

Comment: Isn't it mandatory to have residential trash service in Colusa? I did see on the recology site that Maxwell transfer station will accept bulky items.

Comment: Yeah, it is mandatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sec. 14-3](https://library.municode.com/ca/colusa/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=CH14REGA) of the city ordinances says that

> No person may engage in the business of collecting recyclable
>   materials, solid waste or green waste within the city, or haul
>   recyclable materials, solid waste or green waste through a street or
>   public right-of-way in the city, unless that person has been granted a
>   franchise or license to do so by the city. However, a property owner
>   may occasionally transport recyclable materials, solid waste or green
>   waste produced on his or her own premises to a licensed disposal area,
>   subject to the requirements of Section 14-7 pertaining to solid waste
>   transportation

So that means you can't contract with someone else to haul your trash. You can do it yourself if you can follow the various regulations pertaining to transportation of waste.